# Load different EndpointBehavior from config programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, app-config, endpointbehavior

Is it possible to exchange the endpoint behavior of an endpoint defined in the app.config file?

Basically I have a single endpoint with a defined custom binding. From code I set the endpoint address for the WCF proxy client. I'd like to use different endpoint behaviors depending on the endpoint address.

Pseudocode:

```
var client = new WcfClient("endpointName", new endpointAddress("https://..."));
client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(EndpointBehavior.CreateFromConfig("behaviorName"));
```

Is this (easily) possible? I'd still like to have my behavior definitions in the app.config, but load them dynamically depending on the endpoint's address.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the configuration via System.ServiceModel.Configuration namespace. 
Read the corresponding sections and construct your endpoint/behaviors manually...

You can also create multiple endpoints and instantiate the client by name:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515.aspx

You can also try to use BehaviorExtensionElement from the configuration namespace to try to create a behavior.
I found an example here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2010/05/11/getting-wcf-bindings-and-behaviors-from-any-config-source.aspx

For the server for example: If the ServiceHost instance is already open, you can also access most information from it directly

```
// BaseAddress
Console.WriteLine(serviceHost.BaseAddress);

// Endpoints (non-MEX)
foreach (ServiceEndpoint ep in serviceHost.Description.Endpoints)
{
  if (serviceHost.BaseAddress.Any(uri => uri.Equals(ep.ListenUri) &&
      ep.Contract.ContractType != typeof(IMetadataExchange))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ListenURI: " + ep.ListenUri);
    Console.WriteLine("  Name   : " + ep.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("  Binding: " + ep.Binding.GetType().FullName);
  }
}

// List of MEX endpoints:
foreach (ServiceEndpoint ep in serviceHost.Description.Endpoints)
{
  if (ep.Contract.ContractType == typeof(IMetadataExchange))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ep.ListenUri.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't WCF expose a method to create an endpoint behavior from a named behavior section? After all, WCF does the same when initially constructing endpoints from config only (and it does expose the functionality for `*Binding`).

Comment: if added some more info, have a look into BehaviorExtensionElement

Comment: Can't I create a new behavior similar to how I create a binding from config? `new CustomBinding("bindingname")`. Why isn't there a `new EndpointBehavior("behaviorname")`? I don't want to modify the behavior in code, I want to load a different one from the config. Building it manually by reading the config values via ConfigurationManager doesn't seem right to me (and I fear that the generated behavior might be slightly different from a WCF-generated one and introduce hard to track down errors)

Answer (score -1):

Set the endpoint at runtime:

yourProxy.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Address = New ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("someSvcURL")

Comment: No, I don't want to set the endpoint address, I want to create an EndpointBehavior object by name from the config file.